# LESS Css failed at calculate js variable?

Tags: javascript, html, css, less

I'm new to `LESS CSS`. When I use below `html` and `LESS css` codes the output comes error.

Please fix this problem.

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<title>LESS CSS</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../_s/jquery.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet/less" type="text/css" href="test.less" />
<script src="less.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="box"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

**test.less**

```
@color : #2AA4CF;
@clientHeight: ~`$.trim( $(window).height() ) + 'px'`;
#box
{
    position: absolute;
    background-color: darken(@color, 10%);
    width: 300px;
    height: @clientHeight - 100;
}
```

Output is Error

```
Object # has no method 'operate'
in test.less 
at e.Operation.eval (http://localhost/frames/006/less.js:9:11151)
at Object.e.Expression.eval (http://localhost/frames/006/less.js:9:3533)
at Object.e.Value.eval (http://localhost/frames/006/less.js:9:18173)
at e.Rule.eval (http://localhost/frames/006/less.js:9:12727)
at Object.e.Ruleset.eval (http://localhost/frames/006/less.js:9:13904)
at Object.e.Ruleset.eval (http://localhost/frames/006/less.js:9:13904)
at Object.toCSS (http://localhost/frames/006/less.js:8:10291)
at http://localhost/frames/006/less.js:9:20740
at http://localhost/frames/006/less.js:8:1157
at Object.p.parse (http://localhost/frames/006/less.js:8:10899)
```

Please give me a solution...

Comment: I'm testing this script at all major browsers and get same error.

Comment: I wouldn't mix LESS and JS. LESS should really be rendered and cached server side anyway.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have two problems. The first:

```
`$.trim( $(window).height() ) + 'px'`
```

This code evaluates to `"400px"` (note the quotes `"`). This will make the CSS rule invalid, as it doesn’t use quotes. Also, `$.trim` is redundant since `.height()` returns an integer.

The second problem:

```
height: @clientHeight - 100;
```

This will take the previously created string and try to perform an illegal math operation to it. This is what throws the error.

Here is how you can do it:

```
@color : #2AA4CF;
@clientHeight: `$(window).height()-100`;
#box
{
    position: absolute;
    background-color: darken(@color, 10%);
    width: 300px;
    height: 0px + @clientHeight
}
```

The last code `0px + @clientHeight` is just a trick to add `px` to the variable.

You can probably solve your task using pure CSS instead of calculating in LESS (and also make it scale when the window resizes) using the following code:

```
html,body{ height:100% }
#box{ position:absolute; top:0; bottom:100px }
```